# Replacing values with the value in first row SAS

Tags: sas

I want to replace the values with the first row by group. My data looks like this:

ID Value

A 5

A 4

A 3

B 4

B 3

C 4

And I want the final data looks like this: each ID have the same value as the first one.

ID Value

A 5

A 5

A 5

B 4

B 4

C 4

How should I write the code? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
input ID $ value;
datalines;
A 5
A 4
A 3
B 4
B 3
C 4
;

data want;
   set have;
   by ID;
   if first.ID then _iorc_ = value;
   else value = _iorc_;
run;
```